# The iATS payments "modify your payments" links fail in receipts to donors. Is there a workaround?

Tags: civicontribute, receipts, iats

Using CiviCRM 4.7.22 and iATS Payments 1.6.1. Auto receipts from Civi advise recurring donors that "You can cancel future contributions by visiting this web page" and "You can update recurring contribution amount or change the number of installments for this recurring contribution by visiting this web page" with links. The links fail to display in any browser we've tried. We get only code.

Help! Should we modify the default receipt to eliminate reference to the links or is something misconfigured somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

I am on Civi 4.7.25 and iATS Payments 1.6.1
I just tested our receipt links and they work so it must be a settings issue.

I am just taking some guesses here at some possible settings

1. Administer > CiviContribute > iATS Payments Look for  Enable self updates to recurring ... Is this checked? If not check it and test.
2. **I would check with iATS, Allen or Karin before changing this**
   Administer > CiviContribute > Payment Processors  Click edit to the left of your ACH or CC processor. Find the Site Url and Recurring Payments URL. What do you have there? I have https://www.iatspayments.com/NetGate/ProcessLink.asmx?WSDL There is another url https://www.iatspayments.com/NetGate/ProcessLinkv2.asmx?WSDL but again, I would check with iATS, Allen or Karin before changing this. You can change it and test it. If it works great, if not, just change it back.

But if both 1 & 2 match my settings, then we need to look for something else.

Answer (score 2):

The links have been fixed in CiviCRM Core - they work fine w/ 4.7.25 - I've verified that they work in our recent test matrix (ahead of the 1.6.1 release);

If you decide you'd rather not give your donors the ability to make edits / cancel -> then you can go into the message template [find the right one] -> and then strip out the relevant lines related to these URLs.